# Rufus 3.8 creating windows 7 iso

Tags: windows, flash, bootable-media, rufus

I am using rufus 3.8.1580 to create a windows 7 64 bit iso on a 16 gb flash drive. Do I go with the automatically selected options of rufus got and uefi (non csm) ETFs file type. Or do I change it to mbr... not sure what options because this is my first time making a windows 7 iso

Comment: It all depends on the target computer.

Comment: Can you go into details. So rufus wont pick automatically based on the iso or on the current system I am using? If these things depend on the computer I am going to install on how do I find all this info?

Answer (score 1):

The boot media created by Rufus is dependent on the target system.
In case of a mismatch, the installation will fail.

The possible combinations for the parameters
"Partition scheme", "Target system" and "File system" are as follows:

**UEFI only**

```
Partition scheme: GPT
Target system: UEFI (non CSM)
File system: FAT32
```

**Legacy BIOS only**

```
Partition scheme: MBR
Target system: BIOS (or UEFI-CSM)
File system: NTFS
```

**Dual UEFI + Legacy BIOS**

```
Press "Alt + E"
Partition scheme: MBR
Target system: BIOS or UEFI
File system: FAT32
If the ISO file contains files larger than 4GB, choose NTFS.
```

The ISO to use should be chosen with attention to properties such as UEFI/BIOS
and 32/64-bits target.

[image]